# Install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
tim@tim-virtual-machine:~$ gem install rails --version 3.0.1
Successfully installed rails-3.0.1
1 gem installed
tim@tim-virtual-machine:~$ gem install rails --version 3.0.1
Successfully installed rails-3.0.1
1 gem installed
tim@tim-virtual-machine:~$ gem install rails --version 3.0.1
Successfully installed rails-3.0.1
1 gem installed
tim@tim-virtual-machine:~$ rails -v
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

I have successfully installed rails, but why can't it be found?

Comment: This is best suited to 'super user'.

Comment: Maybe run the gem command a few more times?

Comment: What does `gem env` say? Add its output to the question.

Comment: This happens to me. While playing with package-manager i uninstalled some unknown(not-remember-now) dependency libs,packages from system.

Then when i try to install ruby and rails same error. I searched for rails installed dir and made a symbolic-link to global. Then it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use rbenv, it is a little bit longer to install but it's way more flexible. Among other feature it allow you to install different versions of ruby on you system, and specify which version to use for each project (or conveniently to use a global version everywhere).

I got a doc you can follow, it works very well and I installed several machine with it. If you already installed rbenv, rvm, gem, ruby or rails please remove them before starting

- Works perfectly with Ubuntu 12.04, minor adjustments could be required for other distro
- Some commands need super-user access, I prefixed them with `sudo` and it will ask for your password
- This will install rbenv and all the gems in /opt

Here is the step by step, just copy and paste in your terminal:

* update and install packages ***

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y vim tmux git curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libxml2 libxslt1-dev libxml2-dev nodejs libapr1-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

* install rbenv ***

```
cd /opt
sudo git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git rbenv
```

We will give your basic user full access to rbenv directory, this is needed so you won't have to use sudo for the rest of the procedure, or when updating/installing gems.

Replace `yourself` by your user name:

```
sudo chown -R yourself:yourself /opt/rbenv
```

* setup rbenv ***

```
sudo touch /etc/profile.d/rbenv
sudo echo 'export RBENV_ROOT=/opt/rbenv' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv
sudo echo 'export PATH=/opt/rbenv/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv
sudo echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv
```

* setup rbenv over ssh connection ***

This step needs to be done with super-user privileges

Edit /root/.bashrc file, and add the line `source /etc/profile.d/rbenv` before the line `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`

Do the same in /home/yourself/.bashrc file

* install ruby ***

```
exec $SHELL
mkdir -p $RBENV_ROOT/plugins
cd $RBENV_ROOT/plugins
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
echo 'export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv
exec $SHELL
```

Those 2 lines install ruby and set the installed version by default, you can choose another version of ruby is you wish. Typing in your terminal `rbenv install` and tapping on the TAB key will display a list of available ruby versions

```
rbenv install 1.9.3-p392
rbenv global 1.9.3-p392
```

* verify ruby ***

```
ruby -v
```

The output should be `ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]` or any other version you would have installed. This command should not give you any error

* install base gems ***

```
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri bundler rake 
rbenv rehash
```

* install rails ***

```
bundle exec gem install rails -v 3.0.1
```

* other commands ***

from now on any commands passed to Rails or Rake must be prefixed by `bundle exec` that will ensure all your environment is correctly loaded

- Start rails server `bundle exec rails s`
- Start Rails console `bundle exec rails c`
- migrate database `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

"Bundle" commands can be ran directly, ex `bundle update`