# Bundle install failing on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am trying to get a rails app up in production.  I have uploaded it to the server, and ssh'ed into it without a problem. When I try to run: `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`, I get the following error:

```
Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So, I run `bundle install` and get the following error:

```
Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/rake-10.0.4.gem] in /home/root/myapp
An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

From here, I ran `gem install rake -v '10.0.4' --no-rdoc --no-ri`, and it succeeded:

Yet still, `bundle install` fails with the same error.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `gem update bundler`?

Comment: I just tried, though it didn't help :/  I have also run `gem update --system` `gem install rubygems-update` and `update_rubygems`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys!

I ended up redeploying after running `bundle package`, and then ran `bundle install --deployment` on the server, and now it works.

It looks like I/bundle needed to be more explicit about where to look for the gem files :)

Answer (score 0):

Bundler will try to run Rake that is in your gemfile. You need to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: I get the same error: 
`Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources
Run bundle install to install missing gems.`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your installation is faulty. I suggest you re-do it from scratch, and if you'd like you better use rbenv

Please check this answer [Install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757547/install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/17757826#17757826)

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion will you please try. if you are not root user and running this rake commmad may be it will give error. why not you  try to login as root user and then place and navigate to your code. home/root/myapp to var/yourfolder/yourapp then. check which version or ruby you are using ruby -v it should be 1.9 or above and the same for rails which version of rails you are using.